# On the 1st anniversary of Superuser, I just want to say "Thanks".

Tags: discussion

I have had an abundance of useful help and direction from users. Thanks.

Comment: Same for me. I would have never ventured into learning Linux without the helpful answers of those who know more here. Thank you, thank you :D

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Indeed, and we're saying "thank you" to the whole community that made Super User work!

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/super-user-1-year-anniversary-super-contest/

Answer (score 5):

You're welcome :)

Comment: Same here ;) Ghehe